# Is crredist2005_x64 free?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, c#-2.0

Why I'm asking this question? My story is I developed an c# asp.net 2005 application.
My windows is xp 32bit.
The production Server is windows server 2008 R2 Standard

When I moved to the production server I faced this error:

'Could not load file of assembly CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.2.3.600.0 the system cannot find the file specified.

1- When I got this error I went to my project and I added all Crystal references.
And then I Recompiled the project again but I'm still facing the same error.

2- After days of searching I found an article stating that I have to download  and install crredist2005_x64 on the production server and all my nightmares will over.

Please till me if crredist2005_x64 is free if not tell me what to do?.
Thanking you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I went to SAP and looked up the file it did not state that there was a cost associated with it.